# How to run two different python version in single Django project?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

Currently i am working on django project with python 3.5 and Django 1.9.2. I want to integrated one app(Module) which was build with python 2.7 and Django 1.4 from different django project in my latest project.Can i run two different app with different python and Django in single Django project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, **no**.  An app built for Django 1.4 will almost certainly not work on Django 1.9.

Django does usually offer backwards compatibility, but only on revision numbers of the minor version.  That is, you might expect `1.4.22` to run code written for any `1.4.x` without any change necessary, but a `1.5` release would introduce backwards-incompatible changes.